# Android : Activity restarts when changing the orientation

Tags: android

I have problem with my activity
when I change the phone's orientation, the activity runs the onCreate method agaian
(and my program downloads a file in onCreate)

how can I make activity not restart after orientation change ?

Comment: its not a problem, its the default behaviour. As a solution, you should not download the file once it has been downloaded. So perhaps change the logic of your activity or follow the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for Android Activities - They get recreated whenever you change the device configuration.

To change this behaviour, add this line to the Activity declaration in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

This will tell the system that you handle orientation changes for your Activity on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**android:configChanges** is good, if you're not changing anything, when orientation of activity will be changed.

You can also read about handling orientation change  in documentation:[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

Answer (score 1):

You should properly handle you configuration changes, you can use `onSaveInstanceState` to store information that given file was already downloaded - ie. with path to it. In onCreate `Bundle savedInstanceState` will be non null after configuration change, you can read information on your downloaded file from it.

If you will use `android:configChanges`, then it will not solve your problem. Once you go to other app, android might destroy your activity, when you will go back to your app, android will recreate it again - **and you again will start downloading your file**.

Comment: hmmm ... but in my case it works well. even if I press home button then run the program again. but thanks for the answer. :)